# Powershell Count not returning number of filtered objects

Tags: powershell, count

I have a set of objects (from an import-csv command) I've grouped on one column. I'm filtering this data based on one of the other columns and trying to get a count.

It works fine until there's a single record in the filtered group set. Then it returns nothing (from what I can tell).

```
function TestFun ( $data ) {
  $data | Group-Object GroupColumn | Sort-Object SortColumn | % {
    $currentObj = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group
    $count1 = ($currentObj | Where-Object { $_.FilterColumn -le 2}).Count
    $count2 = ($currentObj | Where-Object { $_.FilterColumn -ge 2}).Count

  }
}
```

That's essentially the code I'm working with, simplified. Like I said, if there's multiple rows ge and/or le 2, it works. If there's only one row, it returns nothing.

I am grouping then expanding the results so that I can iterate through the grouped collection one result at a time.. if there's a better way to do that, I'm open to suggestions. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [array subexpression operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) `@( )`:

```
$count1 = @($currentObj | Where-Object { $_.FilterColumn -le 2}).Count
$count2 = @($currentObj | Where-Object { $_.FilterColumn -ge 2}).Count
```

Even if no items slips through the filter, `0` will correctly be returned

---

Grouping them by the column you see fit is fine, but you may find that `Sort-Object SortColumn` doesn't really seem to do anything.

The objects that `Group-Object` sends on down the pipeline only have 3 properties (`Count`, `Name`, `Group`) and none of those match the property name `SortColumn`, so you might want to move that statement inside the `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
function TestFun {
  param(
    [array]$data
  )

  $data | Group-Object GroupColumn | ForEach-Object {
    $currentObj = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Sort-Object SortColumn
    $count1 = @($currentObj | Where-Object { $_.FilterColumn -le 2}).Count
    $count2 = @($currentObj | Where-Object { $_.FilterColumn -ge 2}).Count

  }
}
```